# Cannot Toggle between Radio Buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display a columns with radio buttons based on a data from mysql table and using php , but I am not able to toggle between the radio buttons. Below is the code.

```html
                while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                    <tr>
         <td border="0" type="hidden"  style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value=<?php echo $rows['member_id']; ?></td>   
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
      
      <?PHP if($_SESSION['user_group'] == 63){
       echo  '<td class="center"><input type="radio" id='?><?php echo $rows['username']; 'name="gp" value="system admin"' ?>
            <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 31 )?'checked':'' ?>'</input> </td>' <?PHP ;         
      echo '<td class="center"><input type="radio" id='?><?php echo $rows['username']; 'name="gp" value="admin"' ?>
      <?php echo($rows['permission']== 15 )?'checked':'' ?> '</input> </td>' <?PHP ;
       echo  '<td class="center"><input type="radio" id='?><?php echo $rows['username'];'name="gp" value="user"'
           ?><?php echo ($rows['permission']== 1 )?'checked':'' ?> '</input> </td>' <?PHP ; }
    
       elseif($_SESSION['user_group'] == 31){             
      echo '<td class="center"><input type="radio" id='?><?php echo $rows['username']; 'name="gp" value="admin"' ?>
      <?php echo($rows['permission']== 15 )?'checked':'' ?> '</input> </td>' <?PHP ;
       echo  '<td class="center"><input type="radio" id='?><?php echo $rows['username'];'name="gp" value="user"'
           ?><?php echo ($rows['permission']== 1 )?'checked':'' ?> '</input> </td>' <?PHP ; }
        elseif($_SESSION['user_group'] == 15){                
       echo  '<td class="center"><input type="radio" id='?><?php echo $rows['username'];'name="gp" value="user"'
           ?><?php echo ($rows['permission']== 1 )?'checked':'' ?> '</input> </td>' <?PHP ; }?>
      
            
                         <td class="center"><button name="update" type="update">submit</button></td>         
                           </tr>               
                    <?php
                }
```

looks like there is an error in the code. Any help with it. The current rendition is below.

[image]

I want to toggle between the radio buttons.

Comment: The way you build the html seems to be a bit off, try to add the name and value of the inputs before the id and the php code

Comment: ok , thanks will try that

Comment: May you share html code rendered in browser?

Answer (score 0):

was able to figure it out. Deleted echo command from the beginning of the html column lines. the code is presented below.

```html
while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                    <tr>
         <td border="0" type="hidden"  style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value=<?php echo $rows['member_id']; ?></td>   
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
      
      <?PHP if($_SESSION['user_group'] == 63){ ?>
                 <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="system admin"
            <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 31 )?'checked':'' ?>></input> </td>
      <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="admin"
           <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 15 )?'checked':'' ?> ></input> </td>
         <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="user"
           <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 1 )?'checked':'' ?> ></input> </td> <?PHP }
    
       elseif($_SESSION['user_group'] == 31){ ?>             
      <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="admin"
           <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 15 )?'checked':'' ?> ></input> </td>
         <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="user"
           <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 1 )?'checked':'' ?> ></input> </td>  <?PHP }
        elseif($_SESSION['user_group'] == 15){ ?>               
       <td class="center"><input type='radio' id=<?php echo $rows['username']; ?> name="gp" value="user"
           <?php echo ($rows['permission']== 1 )?'checked':'' ?> ></input> </td><?PHP }?>
```

This worked just fine.